# Install IIS from C# code

Tags: c#, iis

Is any way that I can install IIS from C# code?
I need to create a deploy installer for my application but I need that IIS to be installed in the machine so I want to verify if IIS is installed using C# code and install it if it's not.

The installer must work with all versions of IIS.

Thanks in advance.

Paulo

Comment: First results from google:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/iisdetection.aspx http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;309506 http://www.appdeploy.com/packages/detail.asp?id=93

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1649180/does-web-platform-installer-support-automation. You can use the Web Platform Installer to start the installation, but it requires user interaction.

Comment: @Jaroslav, if the first result from google for something programming related isn't a page on stackoverflow, then we need to fix that! :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here in the method I used:
I call the followind command line applications for the different IIS versions.

For IIS 5.1 (Windows XP) and IIS 6 (Windows Server 2003):

```
Sysocmgr.exe /i:sysoc.inf /u:IIS_on.txt
```

Content of IIS_on.txt

```
[Components]
iis_common = ON
iis_www = ON
iis_www_vdir_scripts = ON
iis_inetmgr = ON
fp_extensions = ON
iis_ftp = ON
```

For IIS 7 (Windows Vista) and 7.5 (Windows 7):

```
start /w pkgmgr /l:log.etw /iu:IIS-WebServerRole;IIS-WebServer;IIS-CommonHttpFeatures;IIS-StaticContent;IIS-DefaultDocument;IIS-DirectoryBrowsing;IIS-HttpErrors;IIS-HttpRedirect;IIS-ApplicationDevelopment;IIS-ASPNET;IIS-NetFxExtensibility;IIS-ASP;IIS-CGI;IIS-ISAPIExtensions;IIS-ISAPIFilter;IIS-ServerSideIncludes;IIS-HealthAndDiagnostics;IIS-HttpLogging;IIS-LoggingLibraries;IIS-RequestMonitor;IIS-HttpTracing;IIS-CustomLogging;IIS-Security;IIS-BasicAuthentication;IIS-URLAuthorization;IIS-RequestFiltering;IIS-IPSecurity;IIS-Performance;IIS-HttpCompressionStatic;IIS-HttpCompressionDynamic;IIS-WebServerManagementTools;IIS-ManagementConsole;IIS-ManagementScriptingTools;IIS-ManagementService;IIS-IIS6ManagementCompatibility;IIS-Metabase;IIS-WMICompatibility;IIS-LegacyScripts;IIS-LegacySnapIn;WAS-WindowsActivationService;WAS-ProcessModel;WAS-NetFxEnvironment;WAS-ConfigurationAPI
```

Here are some links about this subject:
[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/rakkimk/how-to-perform-an-unattended-install-uninstall-of-iis-5-0-5-1-6-0)
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/309506
http://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/cc731911(WS.10).aspx
http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/132/install-iis-7-from-the-command-line/
http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/479/iis-70-features-and-vista-editions/
http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/135/discover-installed-components/