# Install IIS in windows 7- 64 bit OS using c# code Programatically

Tags: c#, installation, iis-7.5, .net-4.5

I need to check and install IIS IN windows 7- 64 bit OS. using c# code. Is it possible to do this using c# class library ? and how

Kindly advice me on this

Comment: look at [that](http://www.iis.net/learn/install/installing-iis-7/installing-iis-from-the-command-line). Probably that will help. You can run the command line command from your code.

Comment: I think It is possible,
Please [see this][1]



  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3245199/install-iis-from-c-sharp-code

Comment: thanks for the reply.. But its not working in 64 bit OS