# multi storied e-commerce with nop commerce

Tags: c#, nopcommerce

I am using nopCommerce 3.50. And trying to make it a multi storied. Every user signup here will have there specific e-commerce like nopCommerce.

Main features I have to focus is:

1. Every user(store owner(1 store/user)) will have their own subdomain.
2. user's will have full control on their store.
3. They can change theme or configure any settings as an admin of
   NopCommerce can.

So what I am thinking to do is:

1. Create a new project(mother project).
2. Link One NopCommerce Solution with it.
3. when a user signup there, they create a new database as nopcommerce.
4. Name database uniquely for the user.
5. store db name and all user info in mother project.
6. When user sign's in, get the user db from mother db and set the path to nopCommerce Solutions db-path.
7. when a user logs in, user is redirected to a subdomain.
8. and loads the respective database for the user using same server-side and client-side code.

Is it possible or there is any other better way to do this?

Comment: Maybe you should try a more concrete question. I think you look for a system to install nopcommerce on demmand. I think this will be useful for you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1649180/does-web-platform-installer-support-automation